# Can Babel read plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

If we write script using the plain javascript syntax and use babel to compile it, Are babel able to read it and compile it to plain javascript normally, or would that cause an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel can transpile ES6.

ES6 is a superset of ES5 (which is what I assume you mean by "plain JavaScript").

Therefore, yes it can (there just isn't much point in converting ES5 to ES5).